# How do I unfreeze a frozen chat room?

Tags: support, chat, frozen-rooms

I created a room, and now it's frozen due to inactivity.

How can I unfreeze it?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Room owners can't unfreeze a room; you need a moderator to do it.

You could mod flag something  and ask that way, or drop a request into the [The Assembly](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2691/the-assembly) room.

Said moderator would then do so from the "access" tab of the room's overview page (accessed via the "info" link).

Comment: I see that there is not much activity in [The Assemly](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/2691/the-assembly) these days, it was even [frozen for inactivity](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21735542#21735542). Is is still a good place to go with request to unfreeze a room? Would [Tavern on the Meta](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/89/tavern-on-the-meta) be a reasonable alternative? It seems to be rather active these days. Are there other suitable rooms?

Comment: Clarification: the mods in question are per-site mods, right? So apple.se mods can unfreeze apple.se chat rooms?

Comment: @Sparr Any moderator can unfreeze any room, the only time site matters is dealing with private rooms (unless you're talking about Stack Overflow chat; naturally only Stack Overflow mods can help you there)

Comment: FWIW Tavern was also recommended [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100519/exclude-the-main-chat-room-from-automatic-freezing-deletion#comment821226_251532) by Shadow Wizzard.

Comment: @Martin I wasn't aware of The Assembly until now, looks like it's better since it's hosting more moderators.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I am not sure whether The Assemly is better. At the moment, there seem to be rather low activity in that room, in fact, it was [frozen for inactivity](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=frozen&Room=2691&page=1&pagesize=50&sort=newest) several times.

Comment: @Martin oh, so.. guess both rooms are a win-win. (together :))

Answer (score 0):

If you message user [@Floern](https://stackoverflow.com/users/559745/floern) on the [SEBotics](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54445/sebotics) chatroom about the [@GenericBot](https://stackapps.com/questions/7337/generic-bot-a-moderation-chatbot) and ask about the [chatroom antifreeze feature](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49127871#49127871), your chatroom will live eternally.

Comment: Did you ask Floern for permission to speak on their behalf like that? I'm not sure they'll be happy with lots of random people now asking them to put the bot in their chat rooms.

Comment: They said so in the Stack App link. Since it's a public post I assume I have such a permission to spread the word? I'm not sure though

Comment: 1) This was years ago, 2) The one who wants their room to live forever still have to host the bot as far as I can tell, and only then ping Floern asking to add the special command. (better mention it in the answer, unless I'm wrong - you can verify with Floern first.)

Comment: [Sloshy the Thawman](https://stackapps.com/questions/8999/sloshy-the-thawman-a-simple-bot-for-keeping-stackoverflow-exchange-chat-rooms) is a dedicated bot for keeping rooms unfrozen. You should generally have the room owner's approval, and even more ideally mod approval if it's a niche room for a very specific use case.