# Antifreeze for Chat rooms

Tags: feature-request, chat, moderator-tools, frozen-rooms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Don’t freeze a chatroom soon after a mod has unfrozen it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130472/dont-freeze-a-chatroom-soon-after-a-mod-has-unfrozen-it)

Stack Exchange's chat has a cool<sup>*</sup> feature where rooms are automatically frozen for inactivity after like  a couple weeks or something. It's great for auto-freezing the "room for X and Y" auto-generated chatrooms. But it's also the bane of certain specialist chat rooms that are important but rarely used. Moderator only chat rooms (UX's hasn't been used in a year) and *blog rooms* often get deleted and have to be repeatedly unfrozen.

In addition, unfreezing does nothing to stop future auto-freezes. In fact it doesn't even reset the timer it seems, if I don't add a message the bot seems to freeze the chat again the next day, leaving to a time honored tradition of me verbally abusing the chat bot after unfreezing the room to reset the timer:

[image]

I suggest that there should be some way to block future freezes. These anti-frozen rooms could still be cleared up manually by moderators as-needed, but the current situation has lead to me personally undeleting at least 4 different sites' Blog chat rooms (usually as a response to a "WTF happened to our blog room?" mod flag in chat). If it's mod-only and reversible by mods it seems the potential for abuse is extremely low and it would save a lot of annoyance. Blog rooms in particular often have dry spells without actually being of no use.

Freeze-locked rooms should also be immune to the auto-delete script which purges inactive rooms too (I don't know if this is tied to freezing directly, but it always happens eventually after a freeze as well)

<sup>*: this is both a pun and sarcasm</sup>

Comment: Did you ever get a reply from @StackExchange?

Comment: @casperOne he said it's a "chiseled jaw" but I stand by my initial assessment

Comment: What's even the point of freezing in the first place? Was there actually any necromancy abuse going on that caused freezing to be added?

Comment: @Pubby some chatrooms really do fall into disuse and need to go away (like the auto-generated ones I mention). I guess freezing is done before deleting as some sort of warning/more gentle disappearance before deleting. Either way, necroing shouldn't be required for some things

Comment: While I sort of agree with the premise of the suggested duplicate I don't think they're duplicates. The suggested dupe doesn't have all that good of justification and suggests a much different method (auto-lengthen the timeout when unfreezing rooms) rather than an explicit "don't freeze this" option as suggested here

Comment: @Ben: you should probably address the answer to that one here then. FWIW, this is a non-issue for mod rooms.

Comment: @Pubby: "necromancy" isn't even abuse

Comment: @Pubby frozen rooms don't show up on the main list of a site's chat rooms, so it's a way to clear out all the obsolete "Discussion between X and Y" rooms that aren't going to be used again.  Frozen rooms are not automatically deleted, though rooms with only a few messages are.