# Should election chatrooms have a different status when pruning/freezing rooms?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat, election, frozen-rooms

On smaller sites there isn't too much activity in chat - so it is not that surprising that if an election room was created, the "main" chatroom<sup>1</sup> often gets frozen (since it was inactive for 14 days or more).
As a consequence, after the election the only room associated with the site remains the election room rather than some general purpose room.

This is certainly not optimal. (Although on sites which actually do not use chat that much it can be considered a minor problem.)

Fixing this requires some extra work from the moderators - so if this can be automated in some way, there would be one less thing to do for mods (albeit rather minor).

**Suggestion.** Maybe election chatrooms could have some special status - to achieve that they are not taken into account when pruning the rooms. (I.e., that they do not cause the one remaining room for the site to be frozen - even if there is no activity in that room.)

Another way to avoid this problem would be to allow moderators to mark some rooms as "unfreezable" - this was suggested here: [Exclude the main chat room from automatic freezing/deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100519).

Some examples:

- [Bricks](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1653/2021/9/28) was frozen one day after the [creation of the election room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/130033/2021/9/27). It was [already unfrozen](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1653/2023/1/1).
- [ExpresionEngine](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6436/2021/7/29) was frozen 10 days after the [creation of the election room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/127682/2021/7/19).  It was [already unfrozen](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6436/2023/3/15).
- [Homebrew](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/199/2019/6/26) - frozen soon after the [election chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/130426/2021/10/11) was created. It was [already unfrozen](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/199/2023/4/16).
- [Stellar - Lumenati](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/71834/2023/3/18) - frozen about two weeks after the [creation of the election chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/143253/2023/2/28).   It was [already unfrozen](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/71834/2023/4/16).
- [Tor - Exit Node](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/10754/2023/3/29) - frozen soon after the [election room was created](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/144925/2023/3/28). It was [already unfrozen](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/71834/2023/4/16).

<sup>1</sup>I am aware that "main chatroom" is only an unofficial term - the software does not distinguish the room, which was created together with the site, from other rooms created manually. Still, quite often a site has some kind of room intended for arbitrary discussion related to the site (or even for small talk between the users).

Comment: This will require pretty much development effort, and I'm not sure it's worth it. There are bots that can prevent rooms from freezing, there are lots of mods and any one of them can unfreeze any room on se.com chat. (i.e. not SO or MSE)

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard Yes, I have explicitly mentioned in the feature request that this is a rather minor thing. As far as the work needed from developers goes, my guess is that the suggestion in the linked post (that some rooms can be marked as immune to freezing) would be probably easier.

Comment: That is true, but even that requires adding fields to tables, changing existing and ancient code, etc. Falls under "simple", sure, but with the precious little time they spend these days on bug reports and feature requests... maybe better do it on other things. I can only hope one day they will shift the focus to work on what we report or ask here. (Keep in mind I don't say you should delete this, all of this is to explain why I didn't upvote.)