# Make it possible for normal users to unfreeze auto-frozen chat rooms

Tags: feature-request, chat, frozen-rooms

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70201/90848) it isn't possible for normal users to unfreeze chat rooms.

It would be nice to be able to unfreeze rooms that were auto-frozen due to temporary inactivity without having to bother a moderator.

I am aware that it is possible to create a new room, but this is not so useful when there are existing links to the room. Also, if someone finds the first part of the conversation (whether via a link or via a web search), there is no obvious way for them to find the room with the continuation of the discussion (or even to know that one exists).

Comment: +1 Is there any particular reason they ***shouldn't*** be able to do this?

Comment: The rationale is that if the room lacks the activity to stay unfrozen, there's not a compelling reason to allow people to unfreeze it except in exceptional cases (which is handled by moderator intervention). I don't necessarily agree with that, but I'm pretty sure that's an accurate retelling of balpha's explanation from when this came up before.

Answer (score 25):

I think there are two different cases: rooms that auto-froze and rooms that were specifically frozen.  I think it's reasonable to let any participant in the conversation (not any user at all, just the ones who have a stake in it) unfreeze an auto-frozen room, particularly if it's a long-running room with intermittent traffic.

However, as a moderator I would not like users to be able to unfreeze rooms on my site that moderators specifically froze.  Sometimes a room descends into unproductivity and mods might want to shut it down, *but* we don't necessarily want to delete it outright, which takes away access to the whole transcript.  In cases like this freezing is the right solution; it preserves the content but prevents more.  If that decision was made explicitly by moderators it shouldn't be negated by other users -- who, as you say, are already free to just start another room if it's *that* important.

(Note: I'm a moderator on one of the religion sites and this isn't hypothetical; we've had to shut down chat rooms because of arguments.)

Comment: I would +1 if I could, totally agree that specifically frozen rooms should be locked until a moderator unfreezes it OR, perhaps in more extreme cases, a timer consisting of an hour or two in case the moderator has to go?

Comment: I agree that this should only apply to auto-frozen chat rooms and I have edited the question to make this more clear. (Frankly, I don't understand why StackExchange conflates "inactive" with "frozen". Smells like one feature existed and someone got lazy and decided to overload it rather than properly implementing a separate feature.)

Comment: Frozen rooms don't show on the default list for the site (because if they did you'd have tons of clutter from all those "let us take this to chat" spin-offs from posts).  So my guess is that the "frozen" state provides a convenient marker, because you sure don't want to be doing computation ("is this room too old to show?") at display time.  But I'm not an SE dev nor do I know the actual history, so that's just a guess.

Comment: That's what I meant about them reusing one thing for another purpose. Instead of having one flag that means both "frozen by moderator" and also "inactive for a long time" they should have had 2 separate flags.